# How can I make a JMeter test that runs until a specific time?

Tags: jmeter

I need to create a JMeter test that runs until a specific time, entered on the command line. For example:

```
jmeter.bat -DStopAt=10:00:00 MyTest.jmx
```

Can this be done with the 'End Time' in the thread scheduler? Or do I need a 'While' loop? How do I use the 'StopAt' parameter passed in on the command line?

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options:

1. Change JMeter .jmx file before test runs:

   - Enable "Scheduler" and save your test script.
   - Look for the line like

     ```
     <longProp name="ThreadGroup.end_time">1481608595082</longProp>
     ```

     you will have different numeric value. It is basically test stop time in Unix time.
   - Substitute this value with the value you need
2. Do it dynamically, but you will have to do some scripting

   - Add a separate Thread Group
   - Add a Beanshell Sampler to this Thread Group
   - Put the following code into the Beanshell Sampler's "Script" area

     ```
     import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

     String input = System.getProperty("StopAt");
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
     Date now = new Date();
     Date stop = sdf.parse(input);
     Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
     int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
     int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
     int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
     cal.setTime(stop);
     cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
     cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
     cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, day);
     stop = cal.getTime();

     if (now.compareTo(stop) >= 0) {
         log.info("--- Stopping the test --- ");
         SampleResult.setStopTest(true);
     }
     ```

   `SampleResult` - is a pre-defined variable which stands for current (Beanshell Sampler) [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html), see the JavaDoc for all available methods and fields, the most interesting in your case are:

   - [setStopTest()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setStopTest(boolean)) - ASK threads to stop (graceful shutdown may require some time)
   - [setStopTestNow()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setStopTestNow(boolean)) - TELL threads to stop (you may have some extra errors due to abnormal threads termination)

You might also want to check out [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) article for more information about extending your JMeter tests using scripting.

Demo:

[image: JMeter Beanshell Stop at specific time demo]

Answer (score 0):

Create a cron job that executes at the desired stop time

```
killall -9 jmeter
```